# .NET Core 3.1 Alpine image race condition when creating SSL connections

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, ssl, alpine-linux

I'm running into a race condition when establishing SSL connections from .NET Core 3.1-alpine based docker images. We've not seen it happening before when using Debian based images.

Has anyone run into this and know how to fix it?

It only happens with a very small amount of calls (this one occurred in a MassTransit consumer, but we've also seen it happen in controller actions, and establishing MongoDB connections):

```
MT-Fault-ConsumerType:  MyApp.Api.Consumers.ManifestAvailableConsumer
MT-Fault-ExceptionType: System.IO.IOException
MT-Fault-Message:   The process cannot access the file '/etc/ssl/certs' because it is being used by another process.
MT-Fault-MessageType:   .Messaging.VideoUrl.Events.ManifestAvailable
MT-Fault-StackTrace:    at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.FindNextEntry(Byte* entryBufferPtr, Int32 bufferLength)
at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.AppendPrependIterator`1.LoadFromEnumerator()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.AppendPrepend1Iterator`1.MoveNext()
at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CachedSystemStoreProvider.LoadMachineStores(DirectoryInfo rootStorePath, FileInfo rootStoreFile)
at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CachedSystemStoreProvider.GetCollections()
at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CachedSystemStoreProvider.GetNativeCollections(SafeX509StackHandle& root, SafeX509StackHandle& intermediate)
at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509ChainProcessor.InitiateChain(SafeX509Handle leafHandle, DateTime verificationTime, TimeSpan remainingDownloadTime)
at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.ChainPal.BuildChain(Boolean useMachineContext, ICertificatePal cert, X509Certificate2Collection extraStore, OidCollection applicationPolicy, OidCollection certificatePolicy, X509RevocationMode revocationMode, X509RevocationFlag revocationFlag, DateTime verificationTime, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.Build(X509Certificate2 certificate, Boolean throwOnException)
at System.Net.Security.CertificateValidation.BuildChainAndVerifyProperties(X509Chain chain, X509Certificate2 remoteCertificate, Boolean checkCertName, String hostName)
at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.VerifyRemoteCertificate(RemoteCertValidationCallback remoteCertValidationCallback, ProtocolToken& alertToken)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(ProtocolToken& alertToken)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
MT-Fault-Timestamp: 2020-07-27T10:58:37.6888414Z
MT-Host-Assembly:   MyApp.Api
MT-Host-AssemblyVersion:    1.0.0.0
MT-Host-FrameworkVersion:   3.1.6
MT-Host-MachineName:    placement-6d49dd57d9-mq45j
MT-Host-MassTransitVersion: 6.2.0.0
MT-Host-OperatingSystemVersion: Unix 4.15.0.1082
MT-Host-ProcessId:  1
MT-Host-ProcessName:    dotnet
MT-Reason:  fault
dtdTraceTagInfo:    FW4;-111872945;5;-1869341797;401980;0;-1641347138;256;510e;2h01;3h90941b9b;4h06223c;5h01
publishId:  44
```

Personally think it might be a bug in the .NET core Alpine image, should I file an issue on github?

Comment: Did you read the errors? "The process cannot access the file '/etc/ssl/certs' because it is being used by another process."

Comment: @jdweng yes of course, but there's no other process accessing the certificates other than the CachedSystemStoreProvider so that's why I'm tempted to think there's a race condition in the implementation

Comment: Did you see following : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-46950?_ga=2.177807009.523295615.1596019684-1684217888.1593014034

Comment: @jdweng No. Though I have no idea what makes you think this is related, other than it mentions a locked file and docker?

Comment: The link looks like issue is the proxy (RemoteAgentReflectiveProxyFactory) which would be called during the SSL/TLS certification.

Comment: I created an issue: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/2164